# VBA replace a string EXCEL 2019

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I cannot extract the postal/zip code of a given address cell that comes like this :

"108, avenue du Grand Sud  37 170 CHAMBRAY les TOURS".

I have used :

```vb
=RECHERCHE(9^9;--("0"&STXT(A2;MIN(CHERCHE({0.1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9};A2&"0 123456789"));LIGNE($1:$100))))
```

Which sometimes works, sometimes not depending on the street number starting the address (here "108,").

The problem is the space of the pattern "37 170". I would like to remove the blank space in the pattern. Is there a regex way to search this pattern "## ###", and then to remove this poisonous blank space?

Thank you for your tricks.

I have tried this piece of code :

```vb
Function toto(r, Optional u = 0)
Application.Volatile
Dim i%, j%, adr$, cp$, loca$, x
  x = Split(r)
  For i = 0 To UBound(x)
    If x(i) Like "#####" Then Exit For
  Next
  If i > UBound(x) Then
    adr = r.Value 'facultatif
  Else
    cp = x(i)
    For j = 0 To i - 1: adr = adr & x(j) & " ": Next
    adr = Left$(adr, Len(adr) + (Len(adr) > 1))
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(x): loca = loca & x(j) & " ": Next
    loca = Left$(loca, Len(loca) + (Len(loca) > 1))
  End If
  x = Array(adr, cp, loca)
  If 0 < u And u < 4 Then toto = x(u - 1) Else toto = x
End Function
```

The above code works fine for splitting addresses including street number, zip code, and city name. But it does not work when the zip code is `## ###` = 2 digit integer - space - 3 digit integer.

**Edit:** 01 June 2021

Since it seems my question is not clear enough, let's rephrase :

Given an Excel worksheet containing in each cell of column A, from saying A1 down to A10000, complete addresses like this one :

"2 rue Rene cassin Centre Commercial Châlon 2 Sud 71 100 CHALON SUR SAONE"
or this one :
"15, Rue Emile Schwoerer  68 000 COLMAR"

Where "71 100" and "68 000" are a zip code in incorrect format because of the extra space between the 2 first digits and 3 last digits.

I need to split the Ai cell content in order to obtain :

- in cell Bi : the text (street, etc.) placed left before the 2 first digits of the "wrong" zip code,
- in cell Ci : the zip code with its correct format ("71100" and not "71 100"),
- in cell Di : the text (city name) after the zip code.

It's a kind of left and right extraction around the zip code.

The above code that I have posted does not work.

In order to obtain the correct zip code format, I have tried the regex following function :

```vb
Function FindReplaceRegex(rng As Range, reg_exp As String, replace As String)
    Set myRegExp = New RegExp
    myRegExp.IgnoreCase = False
    myRegExp.Global = True
    myRegExp.Pattern = reg_exp
    
    FindReplaceRegex = myRegExp.replace(rng.Value, replace)
End Function
```

But I am unable to determine the correct regular expression pattern to get rid of the space in the zip code.
PEH gave me the following pattern :

`(.*)([0-9]{2} ?[0-9]{3})(.*)`

When using the function, I have tried to define the replacement pattern by:

`(.*)([0-9]{2}[0-9]{3})(.*)`

But it would not work. Hope this will clarify my question.

Any idea is welcome. Thanks

Comment: Is this VBA or Excel workbook formuale only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is VBA, I have a fix for you (please forgive the crappy naming convention, I'm scribbling this down in work while waiting for SQL to refresh):

```
Sub test1()

a0 = Cells(1, 1)  'Get the text, in this case "108, avenue du Grand Sud 37 170 CHAMBRAY les TOURS"
aa = Replace(a0, ",", " ")  'Make all delimiters of same type, so removing commas, you may need to add more replace work here?
ab = Application.Trim(aa)  'Reduce all whitespace to single entries, i.e. " " rather than "  "
ac = Split(ab, " ", -1)  'Now split by that single whitespace entry

Dim txt()

i2 = 0
lastIsNumeric = False
For i1 = 0 To UBound(ac) - 1  'Step through each entry in our "split" list

    If IsNumeric(ac(i1)) = True And IsNumeric(ac(i1 + 1)) = True Then     
        'Two numbers back to back, join
        ReDim Preserve txt(i2)
        txt(i2) = ac(i1) + ac(i1 + 1)
        i2 = i2 + 1
        i1 = i1 + 1
    Else
        'Not two numbers back to back, don't join
        ReDim Preserve txt(i2)
        txt(i2) = ac(i1)
        i2 = i2 + 1
    
    End If

Next i1


If IsNumeric(ac(UBound(ac))) = False Then
    'Need to add last entry to txt()
    ReDim Preserve txt(UBound(txt) + 1)
    txt(UBound(txt)) = ac(UBound(ac))
End If

End Sub
```

edit 2021-06-01:
The above will generate a list (txt) of all the entries within your address. You can then reassemble if you wish, or extract out the postcode only.

If you want it as a function, then it would be:

```
Public Function getPostcode(a0)

aa = Replace(a0, ",", " ")
ab = Application.Trim(aa)
ac = Split(ab, " ", -1)

Dim txt()

i2 = 0
lastIsNumeric = False
For i1 = 0 To UBound(ac) - 1
    If IsNumeric(ac(i1)) = True And IsNumeric(ac(i1 + 1)) = True Then
        'Two numbers back to back, join
        ReDim Preserve txt(i2)
        txt(i2) = ac(i1) + ac(i1 + 1)
        i2 = i2 + 1
        i1 = i1 + 1
    Else
        'Not two numbers back to back, don't join
        ReDim Preserve txt(i2)
        txt(i2) = ac(i1)
        i2 = i2 + 1
    
    End If

Next i1


If IsNumeric(ac(UBound(ac))) = False Then
    'Need to add last entry to txt()
    ReDim Preserve txt(UBound(txt) + 1)
    txt(UBound(txt)) = ac(UBound(ac))
End If

'Re-assemble string for return
rtnTxt = ""
For i1 = 0 To UBound(txt)
    rtnTxt = rtnTxt & " " & txt(i1)
Next i1

getPostcode = rtnTxt

End Function
```

Comment: Hi Deco - it worked here. How are you using it? Are you trying to use it as a function or as a sub?

Comment: Edited now to add in a function that you could use at the worksheet level. But I'd advise you to get your hands into VBA - it would mean you are able to tweak it to give what you want rather than just lift a "black box" solution off here.

Comment: Hi Amiga500, thank you for your post. I apologize, I did not mean anything wrong. Sorry again. I have tried the first sub procedure you gave but it did not work (nothing happens), when launched either from the worksheet or from a module of the worksheet (Excel 2019) containing the cells to clean in column A. The function works but does not return the city in my example : "CHAMBRAY les TOURS". This is what I wanted to say. Again, thank you for your contribution.

Comment: Hi Amiga500, I made a mistake : when the address contains a city name which counts only 1 word like in : "FAMILY VILLAGE 30, rue Amédée Gordini 87 000 LIMOGES", the function does not return the city name "LIMOGES". When the city name counts more than 1 word like in "CHAMBRAY les TOURS", then it works.

Comment: My bad - its a logic hole - will update solution. The problem was my original solution was neglecting the last entry when the 2nd last entry was numeric - that was my mistake. It should only have been neglecting the last entry if it was numeric. (as it would then already have been joined to the 2nd last entry)

Comment: Hi Amiga500, not sure to get what you explain with your numeric entry. The city name is text. But thing is the function only returns a multiple word city name, and nothing when the city name counts 1 word or string only, whatever you define it.

Comment: I tested it with "FAMILY VILLAGE 30, rue Amédée Gordini 87 000 LIMOGES" and it worked OK??? (I got "FAMILY VILLAGE 30 rue Amédée Gordini 87000 LIMOGES" back)

Comment: Hi Amiga500, may I send you a test file ? Complicated to attach anything here.

Comment: Amiga500, I have tried and tried again, cleaned the content of the cells with SUPPRESPACE, no way when the city name counts 1 word only, the code does NOT return the city name, and I only get "FAMILY VILLAGE 30 rue Amédée Gordini 87000" back.

Comment: Hi Amiga500, I went through the code carefully. I got it now, the last entry are not numeric. The sub does not return anything but the function is OK. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If these input strings always have the same pattern, try:

```
=CONCAT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.*0=0]"))
```

[image]

Depending on your needs/edge-cases, you could add more xpath expressions.

Comment: Hi Amiga500, thank you for your post. I will test it an let you know

Comment: Hi JvdV, thanks for your adjusted formula. Seems to work. I will test it and feed you back.

Comment: Hi Amiga500, I have inserted your code in the worksheet (not in a module) and nothing happens.

Comment: Is it possible just to remove this d....d  white space in the pattern "## ###" : always 5 digits separated in 2 groups  and replace it by "#####" ? I have tried to dive into regex method. It is not so simple and moreover seems not to work well in Excel 2019, at least on my pc.

Comment: Sorry JvdV, your formula returns "37" not 37170. In French syntax :

Comment: =CONCATENER(FILTRE.XML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUE(A1;" ";"</s><s>")&"</s></t>";"//s[.*0=0]"))

Comment: @deco, it worked for me as you can see on the screenshot. You may need to use Control+Shift+Enter, if you don't have MS365

Comment: Then you may not have the proper functions available. What version of Excel are you using? @deco

Comment: Hi JvdV, Excel 2019. Please refer to my post I have edited an alternative piece of VBA which is working well only when the French zip code in the cell to split has the following pattern "#####". When the zip code has the following pattern "## ###" it does not work.

Comment: @deco, my suggestion revolves around Filterxml, not VBA code. You commented on the wrong posts

Comment: 5600 lines cannot be treated one by one and I am struggling finding a way. I am unable to set a proper FindReplaceRegex() function because I have no command of its cotrrect syntax. Drives me crazy. Thanks again.

Comment: Then sorry again

Comment: Thought I had mentionned VBA in the title.

Comment: Hi Deco - will reply under my reply rather than under JvdV's answer

Comment: A very tricky way to identify numeric items by multiplication (e.g. check if node contents x 0 = 0), like it :-)